# ggplot2: interquartile range for each group

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, quantile

Based on [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2), I am wondering how I can visualize an interquartile range for each group (Type), where the densities of each group are in one big figure as shown below:

[image: Click here to see the picture]

In this current figure, dots represent x values corresponding to the maximum value of y, where the minimum/maximum values of grey line represent 2.5% and 97.5% [quantile](/questions/tagged/quantile)s of each group.

Here in each plot, I have three dots, which are the maximums in three groups.

HOWEVER, What I need is to have just one dot (one x value) for each group, and I am lost from here.

Please help me!

Just in case, I attached the code that can reproduce the figure.

```
my_data <- data.frame(mean = c(0.04, 0.015, -0.04),
                      stdev = c(0.019,  0.019, 0.02), 
                      Type = factor(c("A", 
                                      "B",
                                      "C")))
# points at which to evaluate the Gaussian densities
x <- seq(-0.1, 0.1, by = 0.001)

# build list of Gaussian density vectors based on means and standard deviations
pdfs <- mapply(dnorm, mean = my_data$mean, sd = my_data$stdev, MoreArgs = list(x = x),
               SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

# add group names
names(pdfs) <- my_data$Type

# convert list to dataframe
pdfs <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, pdfs)

# Summary stat
x.com <- data.frame(pdfs, x)
sum_stat <- matrix(NA, ncol = 7, nrow = 3)
for (i in 1:3){
  sum_stat[i,1] <- min(x.com[,4][x.com[,i]==quantile(x.com[,i], probs=.025)])
  sum_stat[i,2] <- quantile(x.com[,i], probs=.025)
  sum_stat[i,3] <- x.com[,4][x.com[,i]==max(x.com[,i])]
  sum_stat[i,4] <- max(x.com[,i])
  sum_stat[i,5] <- max(x.com[,4][x.com[,i]==quantile(x.com[,i], probs=.975)])
  sum_stat[i,6] <- quantile(x.com[,i], probs=.975)
}
sum_stat <- data.frame(sum_stat)
sum_stat[,7] <- colnames(x.com)[1:3]
sum_stat[,7] <- as.factor(sum_stat[,7])
colnames(sum_stat) <- c("left", "left_val", "max", "max_val", "right", "right_val", "variable")
sum_stat

# convert dataframe to tall format
# library(tidyr)
pdfs$x <- x
tall_df <- gather(pdfs, Type, density, -x)
tall_df$Type

tt <- transform(tall_df,
                Type=factor(Type,levels=c("A", 
                                          "B",
                                          "C")))

ggplot(tt, aes(x = x, y = density, fill = Type, color = Type)) + 
  geom_line() +

  geom_point(inherit.aes = FALSE, 
             data = sum_stat, 
             aes(x = max, y = 0, alpha=0.4),
             show.legend = FALSE) +

  geom_errorbarh(inherit.aes = FALSE, 
                 data = sum_stat, 
                 aes(xmin = left, xmax = right, y = 0, alpha=0.4), 
                 height = 0.1, show.legend = FALSE) +

  facet_wrap(~ Type, ncol = 1) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

Comment: Why did you delete your last question???

Comment: Hi Edward, sorry for deleting the question. You suggested me using facet_grid but this was not the one that I wanted. I specifically wanted to use facet_wrap. Moreover, placing the labels inside the plot was not what I wanted either, as I mentioned earlier in the deleted post. I waited for some other answers, but did not hear anything further. This is the background of deleting the question. Please let me know if I interrupted the stackoveflow environment or violated its rule! I am a newbie.

Comment: Undelete the question and I'll show you how to do it using facet_grid.

Comment: Hi Edward. First, I do not know how I can undelete the question, and second, I figured it out by myself in the meantime. Sincerely thank you for trying to help me! :-)

Comment: OK. That's fine. But I just thought you were too quick to delete the question. Another 3 minutes and I would have posted the required solution using `facet_grid(Type~., switch="y")` + `theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 180))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename the colnames of your `sum_stat` to match variables names of `tt`:

```r
colnames(sum_stat)[7] <- "Type"
```

Then, remove `inherit.aes = FALSE` and just pass `aes` argument in adequate `geom`. Like that when you will call `facet_grid`, it will separate `sum_stat` according `Type` variable:

```r
  ggplot(tt) + 
    geom_line(aes(x = x, y = density, fill = Type, color = Type)) +
    geom_point(data = sum_stat, 
               aes(x = max, y = 0, alpha=0.4),
               show.legend = FALSE, color = "black") +

    geom_errorbarh(data = sum_stat, 
                   aes(xmin = left, xmax = right, y = 0, alpha=0.4), 
                   height = 0.1, show.legend = FALSE, color = "black") +

    facet_wrap(~ Type, ncol = 1) +
    theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
          strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted to have. I have one additional question, if you don't mind. The colors of dots/lines are the same color being used to draw each density plot. Do you know how I can manually change the colors of dots/lines as black, while I keep the beautiful colors for the density lines?

Comment: You're welcome ;) Glad to be able to help. I edited my answer for your additional question. Basically, just move the `color` and `fill` argument into the `aes` for `geom_line` and pass `color = black` for `geom_point` and `geom_errorbarh`. let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is fabulous! I sincerely appreciate it!! :-)